# How can I change the UI language on Windows Thin PC (Windows Embedded 7 Standard)?

Tags: windows-embedded-7

I found an ISO for it and wanted to try it out in a VM. When I click on the Change UI language option in Control Panel, it cannot find lpksetup.exe.
I don't mind using it in English, but since there's a "language pack" available for it, I'd like to use it on my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISO contains the original ms dvd or a customized image ?

If it is a customized image the publisher must have installed a second language. On Windows Embedded not all languages are installed on default.

It is also possible that a Group Policy is set, which prevents installing additional languages. You have to remove this setting.

If you have the original ms dvd you can install a second language with the following procedure.

- Open the original dvd and search for (partial) path ..\DS64SP1\Packages\LanguagePack\ or ..\DSSP1\Packages\LanguagePack\ depending if you have a x64 or x86 installation.
- Open the folder with the desired language.
- Copy lp.cab to c: root of your VM.
- Open "Region and language" control panel.
- Click on "language and keyboard" tab.
- Click on "Install/uninstall languages" button.
- A wizard opens where you can select the lp.cab

Comment: Thanks but in the meantime, I found a custom ISO in Hungarian. I'll try it anyway with the original ISO though.